# Skewness of $Y=\alpha X+\beta$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let Y be a random variable defined by $Y=\alpha X+\beta$, where X is also a random variable. Find the skewness of Y.

- I know that $$Sk_1(Y)= \frac{\mu_3(Y)}{[\mu_2(Y)]^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{\mu_3(\alpha X+\beta)}{[\mu_2(\alpha X+\beta)]^\frac{3}{2}}$$
- $\mu_3(Y)=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mu_Y)^3],\quad \mu_Y=\mu_3'(Y)$
- $\mu_3(Y)= \mathbb{E}(Y^3-3Y^2\mu_Y+3Y\mu_y^2-\mu_y^3)$

So at the end I have to prove that it can be expressed in terms of X or $Sk_1(X)=Sk_1(Y)$

Then how do I resolve this?

Comment: You can write all the (central and non-central) moments of $Y$ in terms of the (central and non-central) corresponding moments of $X$: $E[(Y-\mu_Y)^k] = E[(\alpha X + \beta - (\alpha \mu_X + \beta))^k = E[(\alpha X - \alpha \mu_X)^k ] = \alpha^k E[(X -\mu_X)^k]$.

Comment: Okay, i forgot about that but then i did the steps and all that is equal to $$\frac{\alpha ^2E(X^3)-3\alpha ^2 \mu_X E(X^2)+3 \alpha ^2 \mu_X ^2 E(X)- \alpha ^2 \mu^3 X}{[\alpha ^2 E(X^2)-2 \alpha ^2 \mu_X E(X)-2 \alpha ^2 \mu_X ^2]^\frac{3}{2}}$$ am i right?

Comment: Nevermind, i make a little mistake. But i already solve it, thank you!

Comment: You are making it unnecessarily complicated. Use @Batman's Comment with $k=3$ in the numerator, then again with $k = 2$ in denominator. The $\beta$s disappear at once and $\alpha^3$ in numerator and $(\alpha^2)^{3/2} = \alpha^3$ in denominator cancel. As the Answer (+1) is trying to tell you, the def'n of skewness is devised so that it is invariant under linear transformations such as $Y = \alpha X + \beta.$ (Refers to your prev comment, now changed.)

Answer (score 3):

For any random variable $Z$, define $$\mathrm{standard}(Z) = \frac{Z - \mathbb{E}[Z]}{ \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(Z - \mathbb{E}[Z])^2]}}.$$ 
Notice that $\mathrm{standard}(Z)$ is unchanged under any linear transformation $Z \mapsto \alpha Z+\beta,\; \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$; and that $\mathrm{skew}(Z) = \mathbb{E}[(\mathrm{standard}(Z))^3] $. Thus $\mathrm{skew}(X) = \mathrm{skew}(Y)$.